# Problems with case 'p' || 'P': syntax within a switch statement in C++

Tags: c++, syntax, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I've used the switch statement the following way:

```
   switch (ch){
   case 'P' || 'p': 
        goto balance;
        break;

   case 'r' || 'R':
        goto menu;
        break;

   default:
           cout<<"\t\tInvalid Choice!!"<<endl;
           system ("\t\tpause");
           system ("cls");
           goto menu;
           break;
           }
```

But it seems there's something wrong with the following syntax:

```
case 'r' || 'R'
```

Compiler complains about "duplicate case value". 
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you cite *any* reference, anywhere, that suggests `case 'P' || 'p':` is valid syntax?  Or do you just make up syntax as you go?

Comment: Both 'p' || 'P'  and 'r' || 'R' are 1. Then the compiler says 'duplicate case value'.

Comment: Oh the dangers of translating English to programming. Naturally the error message gives hardly any clue to the real problem.

Answer (score 10):

Change it to

```
case 'P':
case 'p': 
    goto balance;
    break;
```

Using `goto` is usually not a good idea.

---

In your original code, `case 'P' || 'p':` is equivalent to `case 1` as the result of `||` is `0` if both operand are zero, or `1` otherwise. So in the two `case` statement, both `'p' || 'P'` and `'r' || 'R'` evaluated as `1`, that's why you got the warning about duplicate case value.

Comment: I'm sure there will be at least 2 persons defending the usage of `goto`... for some reason it's always that way (I'm not one of them)

Comment: @LihO Actually I'm not against `goto`, that's why I said *usually*, but using it with `switch` `break`, I don't think it's a good idea :)

Comment: If you're going to use `goto`, though, you don't need a `break` right afterward.

Answer (score 8):

```
case 'P' || 'p': 
    ...
```

was meant to be:

```
case 'P':
case 'p':
    ...
```

---

Note that there is another (in this case more reasonable) approach you could use:

```
switch ( std::tolower(ch) ) {
case 'p': 
     ...
     break;
case 'r':
     ...
     break; 

default:
     ...
}
```

you'll just have to `#include <cctype>`

Answer (score 3):

`||` is a binary operator; `'P' || 'p'` evaluates to `true`, because the left-hand operand of `||` is non-zero. Same thing for `'R' || 'r'`. So both `case` statements are `case true:`, and that's what the compiler is complaining about. Separate the values:

```
case 'P':
case 'p':
    menu(); // function call recommended instead of `goto`
    break;
```